# Adding Prototip disabled Mootools. How can these two coexist?

Tags: mootools, prototip

Using both libraries *will* make my life easier. But there seem to be some sort of a problem. Anyone knows the solution to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Dimitar, use one framework where you can, it will make life much easier. Mootools has a raft of goodies that you can plug in and get going with. I suggest you have a look at the clientcide site http://www.clientcide.com/ and their download page where you will find Tips.Pointy which will do just what you want.

http://www.clientcide.com/js

So you know Mootools has done alot of work to allow it to run side by side with other frameworks but any plugins written for them have to use these new features for it to all play nice. All of clientcide's code has been re-written to allow it to use these new "play nice" features in Moo.

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

you can make a non-prototypial library co-exist with mootools or prototype (for example, jquery) but you can't easily get libraries that change / extend the native prototypes to co-exist with each other.

chances are you can get things going if you namespace but any code that you have that depends on the first framework that you load may stop working as expected (prototypes again)

as far as i remember, there were some efforts in the past to get this going - there was a project called SmoothGallery or something.

my advice is - find a tooltip plugin for mootools and drop prototip. forcing two frameworks on your users is a bad practice anyway

good luck :)